# Rails 3: Use a hash of options and values for field selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use this hash as a list of Text and Values for f.select

Controller

```
@asset_status_options = [ { "New - Ordered"    => "0"  },
                          { "New - On Site"    => "10" },
                          { "New - Tested"     => "99" },
                          { "Used - Ordered"   => "1"  },
                          { "Used - On Site"   => "11" },
                          { "Used - Torn Down" => "25" },
                          { "Used - Rebuilt"   => "76" },
                          { "Used - Tested"    => "100"}]
```

View

```
<%= m.select :status, options_for_select(@asset_status_options,"") %>
```

Result of the dropdown is:

```
 { "New - Ordered"    => "0"  }
 { "New - On Site"    => "10" }
 { "New - Tested"     => "99" }
 { "Used - Ordered"   => "1"  }
 { "Used - On Site"   => "11" }
 { "Used - Torn Down" => "25" }
 { "Used - Rebuilt"   => "76" }
 { "Used - Tested"    => "100"}
```

I am looking for a value of 0 and text of New - Ordered etc.

Something simple I think but how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need either:

```
@asset_status_options = { "New - Ordered"    => "0",
                          "New - On Site"    => "10",
                          "New - Tested"     => "99",
                          "Used - Ordered"   => "1",
                          "Used - On Site"   => "11",
                          "Used - Torn Down" => "25",
                          "Used - Rebuilt"   => "76",
                          "Used - Tested"    => "100" }
```

Or:

```
@asset_status_options = [ ["New - Ordered",    "0"],
                          ["New - On Site",    "10"],
                          ["New - Tested",     "99"],
                          ["Used - Ordered",   "1"],
                          ["Used - On Site",   "11"],
                          ["Used - Torn Down", "25"],
                          ["Used - Rebuilt",   "76"],
                          ["Used - Tested",    "100"] ]
```

See the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) for details.

Comment: I appreciate the response (not the tone).  You are right and you answered the question.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome and sorry about the tone. I just wanted to point you to the API. For trivial things like this the API gives an answer right away. Whereas on StackOverflow you have to wait for an answer that may never come.